# Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, androidx

After migrating to Androidx packages using Android Studio menu option Refactor -> Refactor to Androidx...

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

Answer (score 115):

Make sure constraint layout is updated to latest version:

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3"
```

And replace your xml tag names

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout>
```

with

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

in every place where it appears using this shortcut:

Windows: <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd> + <kbd>**SHIFT**</kbd> + <kbd>**R**</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>**COMMAND**</kbd> + <kbd>**SHIFT**</kbd> + <kbd>**R**</kbd>

Comment: The same error may also occur with android.constraintlayout.Guideline, so keep an eye out for that as well.

Comment: It is required to use androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout for BottomAppBar. Any solution for it.

Comment: I had the same problem with androidx.constraintlayout.motion.MotionLayout. Renaming it to androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout compiled and worked for me.

Comment: In my case: constraintlayout:1.1.2 -> constraintlayout:1.1.3.

Answer (score 35):

In AndroidStudio 3.3 RC2 I got it resolved by upgrading -

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

in build.gradle (Module: app)

**Note:** 
This solution is also valid for the release version 3.3 (as per below comment by FireZenk), 3.5.2 (as per below comment by user2350644)

Comment: Valid also for the 3.3 release version

Comment: I've encountered this exception after upgrading to the latest Android Studio Version 3.5.2 and gradlePluginVersion 3.5.2.
Your solution works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Just replace

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout>
```

with

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In your project's xml files.

You can use [Replace in Path](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-and-replace-in-path.html) shortcut in mac **(⇧⌘F or ⇧⌘R)** and windows **(Ctrl+Shift+R)**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Well in my case I've tried **Solution 1** which still was not working. Then I used **Solution 2** along with **Solution 1**.

---

### Solution 1

Updating the current version `ConstraintLayout` in app level `build.gradle` file.

From

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
```

Into

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

---

### Solution 2

Invalidate Caches and Restart Android Studio (If still not working after applying **Solution 1**).

> **File** → **Invalidate Caches / Restart** → **Invalidate and Restart**

I used both of them and It works fine for me.

> **Note:** *Solution 1* is important.

Answer (score 4):

I've also face this issue. This issue occur only for ***constraintlayout dependecy version***.
Use `1.1.3` version & hope your issue will be solved:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to add ConstraintLayout:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

then you need to use it like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        ...>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

or using androidx:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

then you need to use

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        ...
        >

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Do not mix those two.**

Comment: Updating the constrainlayout library from 1.1.3 to 2.0.0-beta2 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Wonderful! This was the perfect answer and sorted me out !!! I used the right syntax like you said !!!

Answer (score 2):

Since the Android Studio is updated to 3.3 it will pop this error. I resolved it by upgrading the version for constraint layout in the `build.gradle` of the app level:

`implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'`

TO

`implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'`

Answer (score 1):

I use an Android Studio 4.1 and this library for constraint layout:

> implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

which is updated on 09-Nov-20 and had the same error with inflating a Constraint Layout.

In my case on my Samsung a40 app worked but on my ZTE nubia n1 app crashed instantly.
I figured that a problem was in my layout background image because my png image was too big for an old device with a different screen resolution than the Samsung a40.
I imported a background png image through the file explorer (drawable - right-click- Show in Explorer) and there was actually the problem.

I tried to import images with Android Drawable Importer but I notice this plugin does not work anymore on Android Studio.

SOLUTION RELATED TO ANDROID DRAWABLE IMPORTER:

If you have already installed the Android Drawable Importer on your Android Studio please uninstall it before you start the process of repairing.
To repair the Android Drawable Importer you need ADI-hack-plugin which you can get by following this youtube video from  [Thomas Samoul](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoA37fOUKeU).

After you repair the Android Drawable Importer just import your image with it and everything will work fine.

Comment: The same for SVG image. I changed `android:background="@drawable/bg_image"` of `ConstraintLayout` to SVG image and got this exception.

Comment: Yeah, the biggest problem is that on some devices everything works fine and on some an app crashes.
I did not try on emulator but i suppose there would not be any crashes.

Comment: Agree with you. But I got this exception on emulator with SVG.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem none of the solutions above worked. The problem, in fact , was caused by a null pointer exception thrown after I switch to NoActionBar theme while the app was using the ActionBar to setTitle(). [The linked stack overflow answer  helped me figure it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144657/android-error-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-app-actionbar-on)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is updated version 3.3. Please remove the previous version constraintLayout

my case used this

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just had to update the **androidx** dependencies to the latest version.

**EDIT**  In build.gradle (app) you have to look for the dependencies which contains androidx. Android studio will show you information about the latest versions of these dependencies. Using that information just the change the dependency version.

Comment: please explain how to do

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidStudio 3.4 I had to downgrade to

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
```

to get it working again.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, it worked for when I upgraded `androidx.appcompat:...'` library to

`'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'` with constraint layout version
`'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'` on Android Studio 3.3

Answer (score 0):

For those who have tried all of the above to no vain, downgrading constraintLayout worked for me (after I wrecked my head for 3 days trying everything under the sun).

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

check if inside your theme file has the right name label

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was testing on Virtual Device API 29. The same error comes out. So updated the constraintlayout version, and change the layout tagname to include widget, but still the app crash with the error.

Then I notice it highlighted Line #8 of my MainActivity. Line #8 is `app:tools=".MainActivity"` and that can't be it. But just before Line #8, there is

```
android:background="@color/material_dynamic_neutral50"
```

(I am guessing this is from the Material Library)

And this is not in my colors.xml. So I add a line in the colors.xml

```
<color name="kelabu">#747679</color>
```

Then change that line to:

```
android:background="@color/kelabu"
```

Then the error cease to happen and I can run in the Virtual device with no issues.